# Get content between two symbols in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have an string output like this one: `.*john*.` and I want to store john in a variable to use it after that, I am trying to use sed to get this part of the string doing this `echo .*john*.|sed -e 's/\\*(.*\)\\*/'` and I have the next error `sed -e expression #1,character 14:order s not terminated`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
echo '.*john*.' | sed 's/^\.\*\(.*\)\*\./\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, looks like the goal is to extract the string S, wrapped within leading and trailing '*'.

Few issues with the REGEXP: 2 will result in grammar error, one will fix the output

1. The 's' command always takes 2 parameters: PATTERN (which was provided), and REPLACEMENT, which should be '\1' here, as the output should contain the name 'john'. The missing REPLACEMENT is the source of the error message (unterminated 's')
2. The PATTERN should quote the opening '('
3. The PATTERN should match the complete line, by prefixing the pattern with '^.*', and appending '.*$' to the end. This will replace the complete line with the matched string.

```
echo '.*john*.' |sed -e 's/^.*\*\(.*\)\*.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using `awk`

```
echo '.*john*.' | awk -F* '{print $2}'
john
```

Setting the Field Separator to `*` and print the second field.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash `=~` operator *to store john in a variable to use it after that*:

```
$ var=".*john*."                                          
$ [[ $var =~ \.\*([^*]*)\*\. ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  # now it's in a var
john
```